# Boost asio networking separate send and receive

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, network-programming

- Server may send to data to client at any time. As in, server contains some sort of send function that another class might call.
- Server reads forever asynchronously
- Same goes for client.

I'm fairly new to networking in boost::asio. I understand the examples on TCP Asychronous servers and clients but these are echo clients/servers. If the server receives data, it will send back right away. But I need the server to receive data, do some other operation for another class, then send given to specific client (Server will have multiple clients connected to it). And this send may be after 1 second or any given amount of time.

In socket programming using the GNU Library, I have this implemented. You have one thread in the server for listening, and another thread for sending. Same for the client. I have looked into this approach in boost:Asio but just cannot get an idea on how to implement this. Anyone can point in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full duplex sockets don't require multiple threads. In fact it's easier if you don't.

If you have multiple threads, you'll have to use a strand to coordinate all asynchronous operations on the socket.

Other than that, it's really just this simple:

Simplest example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf058696ed836622)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace io = boost::asio;
using tcp = io::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {

    session(io::io_service& svc) : _sock(svc), _tim(svc) {}

    void run() {
        ping_loop();
        receive_loop();
    }

  private:
    friend class server;
    tcp::socket        _sock;
    io::deadline_timer _tim;
    io::streambuf      _buf;

    void receive_loop() {
        auto This = shared_from_this();
        io::async_read_until(_sock, _buf, "\n", [This,this](error_code ec, size_t) {
                if (ec)
                    std::cerr << "Receive error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                else {
                    std::cout << "Received '" << &_buf << "'\n";

                    // chain
                    receive_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    std::string _ping = "ping\n";

    void ping_loop() {
        _tim.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(100));
        auto This = shared_from_this();

        _tim.async_wait([This,this](error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    io::async_write(_sock, io::buffer(_ping), [This,this](error_code,size_t) {});

                    // chain
                    ping_loop();
                }
            });
    }
};

class server {
  public:

    void start() {
        _acc.bind({ io::ip::address_v4{}, 6768 });
        _acc.listen(5);
        accept_loop();

        _svc.run(); // TODO thread? shutdown?
    }

  private:

    void accept_loop() {
        auto sess = std::make_shared<session>(_svc);

        _acc.async_accept(sess->_sock, [this,sess](error_code ec){
                if (ec) {
                    std::cerr << "Accept error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                } else {
                    sess->run();

                    // chain
                    accept_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    io::io_service _svc;
    tcp::acceptor _acc { _svc, tcp::v4() };
};

int main() {
    server s;
    s.start();
}
```

When running a client / client like this:

```
while sleep 1; do date; done | nc localhost 6767
```

Server output like:

```
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:08 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:09 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:10 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:11 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:12 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:13 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:14 CET 2015
'
Received 'Thu Nov 12 10:24:15 CET 2015
'
Receive error: End of file
```

While client receives continuous

```
ping
ping
...
```

Comment: How would you perform send? Send operation will be requested from an another class

Comment: Elaborate example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b51caf6cb7d27b8e (look at the `broad_cast` implementation. In real life you will probably have something for a specific connection)